# TransferToGame with UIButton - How? (Lua)

Tags: user-interface, lua, coregames

I am currently making a main menu for my game, and one of the buttons (a "Deploy" button) needs to transfer the player to a map. However, I can't get the "Deploy" button to work.

```js
local button = script.parent
local gameteleport = script:GetCustomProperty("Game")
local Deploy = script:GetCustomProperty("Deploy"):WaitForObject()


Deploy.isEnabled = true   --EnableUI
UI.SetCursorVisible(true)
UI.CanCursorInteractWithUI(true)

function OnClicked(whichButton)
    print("button clicked: " .. whichButton.name)
    player:TransferToGame("703a40/map-the-cauldron")
end

function OnHovered(whichButton)
    --print("button hovered: " .. whichButton.name)
end

function OnUnhovered(whichButton)
    --print("button unhovered: " .. whichButton.name)
end

button.clickedEvent:Connect(OnClicked)
button.hoveredEvent:Connect(OnHovered)
button.unhoveredEvent:Connect(OnUnhovered)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only issue you are having is the network context from which you are calling the "*TransferToGame*" function. The "*TransferToGame*" function needs to be called from a server-side script as opposed to a client-side script. You can do this by using an event broadcasted from the client to the server to notify the server which player to transfer.

**Client-Side Script:**

```
local button = script.parent
local gameteleport = script:GetCustomProperty("Game")
local Deploy = script:GetCustomProperty("Deploy"):WaitForObject()


Deploy.isEnabled = true   --EnableUI
UI.SetCursorVisible(true)
UI.CanCursorInteractWithUI(true)

function OnClicked(whichButton)
    print("button clicked: " .. whichButton.name)
    --Tell the server to transfer the player
    Events.BroadcastToServer("Transfer Player")
end

function OnHovered(whichButton)
    --print("button hovered: " .. whichButton.name)
end

function OnUnhovered(whichButton)
    --print("button unhovered: " .. whichButton.name)
end

button.clickedEvent:Connect(OnClicked)
button.hoveredEvent:Connect(OnHovered)
button.unhoveredEvent:Connect(OnUnhovered)
```

**Server-Side Script:**

```
--This function is called when the "Transfer Player" message is received
function OnTransfer(player)
    --transfer the player
    player:TransferToGame("703a40/map-the-cauldron")
end
--Connect the "OnTransfer" function to the "Transfer Player" event
Events.ConnectForPlayer("Transfer Player", OnTransfer)
```